# Unable to use barcodescanner after using torch

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I'm using Phonegap 2.5 and I've downloaded the latest versions of the BarcodeScanner and the Torch. If I use the torch and then try to scan an image I get "Sorry, the Android camera encountered a problem. You may need to restart the device.". I'm thinking that the torch is not letting go of the FLASHLIGHT.. Anyone know of a way to force it to release, if you agree that is the issue?

```
03-29 16:36:53.094: I/dalvikvm-heap(15000): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.967MB for 3686416-byte allocation
03-29 16:36:53.104: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(15000): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
03-29 16:36:53.104: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(15000): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
03-29 16:36:53.104: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(15000): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
03-29 16:36:53.114: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(15000): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
03-29 16:36:53.114: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(15000): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.204: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.214: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.224: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.224: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x00000000
03-29 16:36:53.234: I/PlatformSupportManager(15000): Using implementation class com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.HoneycombAsyncTaskExecInterface of interface com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.AsyncTaskExecInterface for SDK 11
03-29 16:36:53.404: I/PlatformSupportManager(15000): Using implementation class com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.GingerbreadOpenCameraInterface of interface com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.OpenCameraInterface for SDK 9
03-29 16:36:53.404: I/GingerbreadOpenCamera(15000): Opening camera #0
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000): Unexpected error initializing camera
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:340)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:302)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.GingerbreadOpenCameraInterface.open(GingerbreadOpenCameraInterface.java:57)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraManager.openDriver(CameraManager.java:78)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.initCamera(CaptureActivity.java:701)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.surfaceCreated(CaptureActivity.java:384)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:569)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:174)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:680)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1842)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
03-29 16:36:53.414: W/CaptureActivity(15000):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 16:36:53.424: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x01030042
03-29 16:36:53.424: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x01030042
03-29 16:36:53.434: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x01030044
03-29 16:36:53.434: W/asset(15000): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0208000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x01030022, style=0x01030044
```

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever find out how to use both?

Comment: Yes. I'll post a fix when I get home tonight. I just seen this. Sorry.

Comment: If you could that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Try use this phonegap plugin instead normal barcode scanner.

https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin